# Apache Configuration: How to deny from env=protected but allow from env=errorhandler?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, environment-variables

I've written this .htaccess configuration, which works:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^staging\. protected
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\. protected

AuthType basic
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"

Order deny,allow
deny from env=protected
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

It checks if hostname starts with "staging." or "dev." and set the environment variable "protected". If it is set, the browser will ask for the password. If not, no access restriction takes affect. This is the expected behaviour.

Unfortunately the CMS I am working with does an own HTTP request from localhost to fetch the error page internally, if a 404-error occures. But the server itself is not authenticated, so this fails.

I was able to set another environment variable like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "404$" errorhandler
```

But it has no effect, even if I change the last block like this

```
Order allow,deny
allow from env=errorhandler
deny from env=protected
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
```

What do I need to change, to ask for password if env=proctected is set, but skip the password, if env=errorhandler is set, too? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try these directives:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^(dev|staging)\. protected
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI 404 !protected

AuthType basic
AuthName "Protected"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
Satisfy any

Order allow,deny
allow from  all
deny from env=protected
```

Comment: Sure, let me know if you run into any problems with this.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. All calls remain in 401 responses.